# Let $X$ be a random variable, prove that for any real number $a$, that $\mathrm{Var}(X) \le E[(X-a)^2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing, variance

I have the following question:

> Let $X$ be a random variable, prove that for any real number $a$,
> $$\mathrm{Var}(X) \le E[(X-a)^2].$$

The question gives a hint by saying:

> Write $\mathrm{Var}(X) = E[(X-a-(E[X]-a)^2)$.

So I thought about just expanding the LHS:

\begin{align*}
E[(X-a)^2]
&=  E[X^2 - 2aX - a^2] \\
&=E[X^2] - 2aE[X] - a^2
\end{align*}
Since $a$ is a constant $E[a^2]= a^2$.

I did not see anything obvious so I did the same thing to the RHS:

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}(X)
&= E[(X - a - (E[X] - a))^2] \\ 
&= E[X] - E[a] -E[(E[X])^2 - aE[X] +a^2] \\ 
&= E[X] - a - (E[X])^2 - aE[X]+a^2
\end{align*}

But now I am stuck because I feel like a did a ton of algebra, and don't know how to proceed. Any help on to get unstuck (or if I misinterpreted something) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume it should be $\text{Var}(X) \leq E[(X - a)^2]$, correct, not $=$?

Comment: Yes it is, I will update it

Comment: FYI, you messed up your algebra on the RHS from the first to the second line; you have to expand the ENTIRETY of $(X - a - (E[X] - a))^2$, not just $(E[X] - a)$.

Comment: Why $-a^2$? It should be $+a^2$ ($E[(X-a)^2] =  E[X^2 - 2aX + a^2])$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - E^2[X]$. Let's see how can we massage $E[(X - a)^2]$:

\begin{eqnarray}
E[(X - a)^2] &=& \\
             &=& E[X^2 - 2 a E[X] + a^2] \\
             &=& a^2 - 2aE[X] + E[X^2] \\
             &=& (a - E[X])^2 + E[X^2] - E^2[X] \\
             &=& (a - E[X])^2 + \operatorname{Var}(X)
\end{eqnarray}

This concludes the proof :)

Comment: I see that $a^2 - 2aE[X] + E[X^2] = (a - E[X])^2$, but where does $E[X^2] - E^2[X]$ come from?

Comment: More simply:  $\text {Var}(X)=\text {Var} (X-a)=E[(X-a)^2]-E^2[X-a]$

Comment: @James I made a typo, which is now corrected ($E[X^2]$ in the third line was previously $E[X]^2$).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Antoine's answer.

We know $\sigma^2 = E[(X-\mu)^2]$ where $\mu = E[X]$. Then (typical trick) sum and substract $\mu$ from the desired inner expression:

$$\begin{align}
E[(X-a)^2]&=E[(X-\mu + \mu -a)^2]\\
 &= E[ (X-\mu)^2 + 2(\mu-a)(X-\mu)+(\mu-a)^2]\\
 &= \sigma^2 + 2(\mu-a)E[X-\mu]+(\mu-a)^2\\
 &= \sigma^2 + (\mu-a)^2
\end{align}$$

which implies $E[(X-a)^2] \ge \sigma^2$, with equality iff $a=\mu$.